# Cannot open serial communication port with Swift/ORSSerial

Tags: swift, macos, orsserialport

I'm trying to open up a USB-port for serial communication with a STM32 microcontroller which is under the path "/dev/cu.usbmodem103". My pc is the MacBook Pro 2021 (M1 Pro) running MacOS 12.3. I'm using the SwiftUI environment and using the ORSSerial library to open the port and reading the data. I just followed the instruction of the given example to open the port but somehow I never get the notification by the library that the port was open. The code is the following.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import ORSSerial

class SerialHandler : NSObject, ORSSerialPortDelegate, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var inputText: [String] = []
    @Published var serialPortStatus = false
    
    var serialPort: ORSSerialPort?
    
    func serialPort(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort, didReceive data: Data) {
        if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
            print(string as String)
            inputText.append(string as String)
        }
    }

    func serialPortWasRemovedFromSystem(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort) {
        self.serialPort = nil
        print("Serial port \(serialPort.name) is removed.")
    }
    
    func serialPortWasOpened(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort) {
        self.serialPortStatus = true
        print("Serial port \(serialPort.name) is open.")
    }
    
    func serialPortWasClosed(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort) {
        self.serialPortStatus = false
        print("Serial port \(serialPort.name) is closed.")
    }
    
    
    func openPort(port: String, baudrate: Int) {
        self.serialPort = ORSSerialPort(path: "/dev/cu.\(port)")
        if let serialPort = self.serialPort {
            print("Serial port is not nil")
            serialPort.delegate = self
            serialPort.baudRate = 115200
            serialPort.parity = .none
            serialPort.numberOfStopBits = 1
            serialPort.open()
        }
        else {
            print("Serial port is nil")
        }
    }
    
    func closePort() {
        if let serialPort = self.serialPort {
            serialPort.delegate = nil
            serialPort.close()
        }
    }
    
    func getAvailablePorts() -> [String] {
        let availablePorts = ORSSerialPortManager.shared().availablePorts
        var ports: [String] = []
        for i in availablePorts {
            ports.append(i.name as String)
        }
        
        return ports
    }
}
```

Also I activate the USB checkbox under Project->Targets->Signing&Capabilities->USB and added the following key to a plist file: com.apple.security.device.serial TRUE.
The plist file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.device.serial</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What could be the reason that the port won't open?

Comment: Do you do `serialPort.delegate = self` ?

Comment: Yes just before serialPort.baudrate in the openPort-function

Comment: Okay I solved it. I did implemented the key in the wrong file. It has to be implemented in the root folder. The path of it is under: Project -> Target -> Build Settings -> Signing -> Code Signing Entitlements.